# Possible memory leak with Parallel.Invoke()?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

Over the past few days I have been trying to identify a memory leak in my application. I have good reasons to believe that it comes from this piece of code;

```
List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
List<Action> Actions = new List<Action>();

while (true)
{
    //The queue is a singleton which is used by multiple threads.
    //This method grabs the lock and dequeues 500 items at a time.
    Items = ItemQueue.Instance.DequeuePackageByAmount(500); 

    if (Items == null) break;

    for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++)
    {
        int copy = i;
        Actions.Add(new Action(() => DoSomethingWithItem(Items[copy])));
    }

    Parallel.Invoke(new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 500 }, Actions.ToArray());

    Items.Clear();
    Actions.Clear();
}
```

`Item` does not contain any un-managed resources that should be disposed. For the sake of completeness;

```
public class Item
{
    public ICollection<string> SomeCollection;
    public string SomeString;
}
```

And, of course;

```
public void DoSomethingWithItem(Item item)
{
    ItemProcessor processor = new ItemProcessor();
    processor.Process(item);
}

public class ItemProcessor
{
    private DbContextWrapper db;

    public ItemProcessor()
    {
        //DbContextWrapper contains methods which talk to the database.
        //Every method has a using(), so there should be no DbContext resources
        //left undisposed.
        db = new DbContextWrapper();
    }

    public void Process(Item item)
    {
        foreach(string s in item.SomeCollection)
        {
            //check some things and push it to the next queue if valid
        }
    }
}
```

I know I should not ask *please find the memory leak* since the code is pseudo. Therefore;

**Is it possible that this piece of code is vulnerable to a memory leak and if yes, where?**

**EDIT 1:**

To further explain *I have good reasons to believe that it comes from this piece of code*; I have tested several pieces of the code and this piece was the piece that allocated the most memory. After about 5 minutes, my application uses about 1.6G RAM and shortly after that, it crashes with an `OutOfMemoryException`.

Also, to further explain the `DbContextWrapper`, it looks like this;

```
public class DbContextWrapper
{
    private string ConnectionString;

    public DbContextWrapper()
    {
        //Create ConnectionString with EntityStringBuilder etc.
    }

    public int AnyMethod(int someExistingId)
    {
        using(DbContext db = new DbContext(ConnectionString))
        {
            return db.table.Where(t => t.id == someExistingId).First();
        }
    }
}
```

AFAIK, this way there should be no unmanaged resources left undisposed.

Comment: You can look at your code for hours... or you canmake memory dump and analyse it. Did you try? Or you can use memory profiler - did you tried it?

Comment: You said *I have good reasons to believe that it comes from this piece of code*, and How? Did you profile your application?

Comment: Specifying 500 in MaxDOP isn't going to run faster, it will simply result in 492 inactive tasks, assuming you have a quad code with hyperthreading. Why are you trying to run a different action for each item instead of just doing a Parallel.ForEach on the data? You are creating 500 delegates for no reason.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that is true. 500 was a random number actually. But that doesn't solve it, right?

Comment: Please share your definition of "memory leak". What do you see happening and why do you think this code causes it? I suspect the DbContextWrapper, as a DbContext is meant to be short-lived as it caches items it reads from the database.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I could expect that question. I have launched the code in pieces and this piece seemed to be the only one which allocated that much memory. I thought that would be the profile...

Comment: When dealing with memory leaks, assumptions are the worst mistakes you can make. Use a memory profiler, find where the memory is leaked and also why the objects are rooted.

Comment: @DionV. it means the code tries to second-guess the framework in a bad way, resulting in a leak of actions, delegates and tasks, that have to be garbage collected and scheduled in far more threads than needed, resulting in a lot of thread construction and switching

Comment: Use a memory profiler to see what gets allocated. The code is allocating one ItemProcessor per item that includes a DbContext (which by default caches the items it loads) that doesn't get disposed. You may be loading the entire database in memory this way, or at least, the same data 500 times

Comment: I edited the question with more info. I will continue going through the comments now.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it does get disposed, as I told already in the comments above. I added it to the edit for more clarity.

Comment: The code needs rewriting and simplifying. Each edit reveals more issues. Eg. each using results in yet another database connection, each method in yet another query. That's a lot of time wasted in roundtrips, lots of contexts etc. Collect the IDs needed in each batch and load the items with a simple command, eg with `Where(t=>batchIds.Contains(t.Id))`. This will result in a `WHERE ID IN (....)` clauses.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos at first, you don't know anything about the application. At second, this does not fix any memory issues. If you are willing to comment on how the code looks, go to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Please stop wasting my time.

Comment: I never commented on how the code looks. First, you don't provide enough code to diagnose the problem. As it is, each edit uncovers another problem. Second, I think I've described a lot of issues already that do result in memory leaks. Third, I'd use Visual Studio's Profiler or a tool like [Memory Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/) to see what is actually going. Memory Profiler's snapshot comparison will show you the objects that were allocated between one memory snapshot and the next while the application is still running

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 1. *I never commented on how the code looks*, *The code needs rewriting and simplifying.*. 2. Actually not. 3. I am looking into that now.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have debuggers/profilers etc:
If it is a managed leak (not an unmanaged leak) you are hunting down you could try (out of my memory):

Run application until you notice a mem leak.
Take a dump (before the exception occurs !!).
Open in Windbg and run (assuming .NET 4):

```
.loadby sos clr  
!dumpheap -stat
```

Then look at the last objects in list (with most instantiated objects) and identify an object type you would not expect with that many instantiations. (One of yours or one out of Parallel etc).

run on that type:

```
!dumpheap -type [yourType]
```

Watch Out: the result lists all types that start with the name like the example System.Threading.Thread.
You'll get a list similar to (example of System.Threading.Thread):

```
...//single objects list
33767510 71d41144       56     
42fb29e4 71d41144       56     
42fbf2f0 71d41144       56     
42fd6e18 71d41144       56     
42fe62b0 71d41144       56     
430715fc 71d41144       56     
4344374c 71d41144       56     
total 372 objects
Statistics: // summary of the classes listed in single object list
      MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
71d2ebd8        1           24 System.Threading.ThreadPoolRequestQueue
714c52b4        1           32 System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler
71d40f44        2          144 System.Threading.ThreadAbortException
71d285a4       41          820 System.Threading.ThreadHelper
71d27f48       82         2624 System.Threading.ThreadStart
>>71d41144      245        13720 System.Threading.Thread
```

The first part is a list of all objects in memory. The marked type in the list is the one chosen for the example.
The second parameter in the objects list is the Method Table of the type. This is how you can identify different types in the object list.
Take several of the Addresses of the object list (like 42fd6e18 or 4344374c for example) and run:

```
!gcroot <address>
```

for several of the addresses. You will get lists of objects that are holding references to the suspected type. You have to find a reason for objects at the top of the list why it is holding your type (and actually you believe it shouldn't)